# SharePoint Search Error "There was an exception in the Database"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

Created new content sources for SharePoint Search 2013 a week friday ago, returned content no problem. On the following Monday Search stopped working and displayed the error message "There was an exception in the Database".

In the ULS logs, i got an error messages 
"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (xxxxxxxxx): Could not find stored procedure 'proc_MSS_GetUrlMapping'"

"SqlError: 'Could not find stored procedure 'proc_MSS_GetUrlMapping'.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 2812 State: 62 Class: 16 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 1 Server: 'xxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx'"

"Exception occured in scope Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries. Exception=System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: There was an exception in the Database. Please retry your operation and if the problem presists, contact an administrator."

I have tried resetting the index and doing a full crawl etc but no joy. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Josh

Comment: Try to open the content database through SSMS has sysadmin and check if the *proc_MSS_GetUrlMapping* exist. Maybe a permissions problem ...

Comment: Hi Max, in SSMS and got the content db open. What level of access does sysadmin need? Checked the stored procedures and cannot find the proc_MSS_GetUrlMapping in the content db. Any further help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sysadmin is the main admin of SQL Server. Open SSMS and check under security if the current user have sysadmin role also check if the user of app pool of sharepoint have sufficient permission to access the content db (and for execute the stored proc)

Comment: Ok there is a sysadmin role under security in the content db. Should the sysadmin be db_owner or any other roles? The App pool account has db_securityadmin and SPDataAccess roles for the content database

Comment: Hi Josh / Max
Were you able to find solution for this.. ? We too are facing same issue